# Hibernate ignores the schema name while calling nextval() - from postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, sequence, nextval

My pojo definition worked fine till I used Postgres 9.x,  When I changed the database to postgres 12 I get **Sequence not found** error when inserting a new row to a table. When I debugged the sql statements run in the database I found that hibernate ignored the schema name.

> Postgres 9 : select nextval('ita.ita_settings_is_is_id_seq').... 
>   Postgres 12: select nextval('ita_settings_is_is_id_seq')....

My Pojo definition is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ita.ita_settings_is")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "settingItaIdSeq", sequenceName = "ita.ita_settings_is_is_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class itaSettings  implements Serializable {


 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "settingitaIdSeq")
 @Column(name = "is_id")
 private int id;
```

Comment: Did you upgrade the JDBC driver to the latest one? And from which 9.x version exactly did you upgrade? ("9.x" covers **7** major versions)

Comment: Thank you for the clue. We did that and solved issues related to that upgrade and problem is solved.
Earlier we tried to update the hibernate jar, which did not helped